# Split column into multindex columns based on unique values

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

If I have a data frame

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'IDs': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                            'two'],
                    'X': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                    'Y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
```

that looks like

```
    IDs     X   Y
0   one     A   1
1   one     B   2
2   one     C   3
3   two     A   4
4   two     B   5
5   two     C   6
```

what is the best way to output the format such as:

```
IDs  one     two    
Pos X   Y   X   Y
0   A   1   A   4
1   B   2   B   5
2   C   3   C   6
```

The `ID's` can change in name and length (i.e. number of actual `ID's`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, then create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and last [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for change level order:

```
df = (test.set_index([test.groupby('IDs').cumcount(), 'IDs'])
           .unstack()
           .rename_axis(('Pos','IDs'), axis=1)
           .swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1)
           .sort_index(axis=1))
print (df)
IDs one    two   
Pos   X  Y   X  Y
0     A  1   A  4
1     B  2   B  5
2     C  3   C  6
```